# SearchView цвет текста

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте, как изменить цвет текста для `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`
В стилях параметр `android:searchViewTextField` определяет заливку, а не цвет текста.

Answer (score 1):

Если используется AppCompat 21, то можно просто определить в стиле темы.

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/MySearchViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MySearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <!-- The layout for the search view. Be careful. -->
    <item name="layout">...</item>
    <!-- Background for the search query section (e.g. EditText) -->
    <item name="queryBackground">...</item>
    <!-- Background for the actions section (e.g. voice, submit) -->
    <item name="submitBackground">...</item>
    <!-- Close button icon -->
    <item name="closeIcon">...</item>
    <!-- Search button icon -->
    <item name="searchIcon">...</item>
    <!-- Go/commit button icon -->
    <item name="goIcon">...</item>
    <!-- Voice search button icon -->
    <item name="voiceIcon">...</item>
    <!-- Commit icon shown in the query suggestion row -->
    <item name="commitIcon">...</item>
    <!-- Layout for query suggestion rows -->
    <item name="suggestionRowLayout">...</item>
</style>
```

Если поздняя версия совместимости, то так

```
//Setup searchView text color
EditText v = (EditText)searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
if (v != null) {
   v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вам надо в стилях переопределить цвет текста EditText:

```
<style name="MyEditTextstyle">
   <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_blue</item>
</style>
```